# Is it inconsistent for an interdisciplinary question to be on topic in one site but not in another?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, scope, rules

A religious question, "Christianity, Judaism, and Islam worship the same God?" is on topic in [Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1932/christianity-judaism-and-islam-worship-the-same-god) but not [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/christianity-judaism-and-islam-worship-the-same-god) or [Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18254/christianity-judaism-islam-and-god)

Is this seeming inconsistency common on Stack Exchange? I can ask about a philosophical question involving mathematics and physics in the Philosophy, Mathematics and Physics Stack Exchanges.

Answer (score 10):

First, this is an example of what is called cross-posting: Posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites without changing the focus of the question to suit the site. The reason that this behavior is generally discouraged is that it splits up information, which is more unhelpful than one would think.

The version on Christianity was deleted, so I have no information on that, but the other two versions were asked within about eight minutes of each other. That might have affected the decision to close on Mi Yodeya (most likely not, as it was closed quickly, but it might have affected any decisions to not reopen).

Second, each site is free to decide its own policies. The question involved [Topic X], [Topic Y], and [Topic Z]. Just because the site about [Topic 1] thinks it's okay to have questions about [Topic 1] and [Topic 2] and [Topic 3] doesn't mean that the sites for [Topic 2] and [Topic 3] have to agree. This appears to be what happened on Mi Yodeya.

Each community is different, and each site is different. Different rules apply.

Comment: I didn't know about that last one. thank you! is it really cross posting? i view cross posting as asking a statistics problem on both mathematics and statistics stackexchange. the answers will most definitely be the same. the religious one is asking for different perspectives on the same thing. the answers will not necessarily be the same.

Comment: @RedRackham It's cross-posting; the same question is being asked with minimal modifications. There would have to be drastic changes in it to show a definitive focus on a different audience.

Comment: the same question is asked but answers are not expected to be the same. i thought cross posting is generally bad because it wastes people's time like if I ask a mathematical physics question on both mathematics and physics stackexchange. however, asking about perspectives from different religions, i don't think it is cross posting imo. would it be cross posting to ask christianity, islam, judaism and hinduism their opinions on abortion (which I did)?

Comment: @RedRackham A good question on Stack Exchange should have a right answer. For example, your question about abortion sounds like it might be off-topic anywhere (though I don't know for sure) because it's what we call **primarily opinion-based**. There's no one single answer, and in the cases of questions like those, discussions and arguments are bound to happen, which aren't good. I understand that you can ask about how different religions view an issue, but the issue would have to be *specific to that religion*.

Comment: (More on Mi Yodeya's policy regarding comparative religion questions http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/828/759)

Answer (score 2):

Basically it boils down the the fact that cross posting is frowned upon.

You've probably hit on one a very few questions that would be on topic on several sites. However, you should really tailor your question to the audience you are asking it of. So in your mathematics/physics example you'd emphasise the maths aspects for the maths site and the physics aspects for the physics site.

I know it sounds simplistic when it's written out, but it really is that simple.

Comment: is it really cross posting? i view cross posting as asking a statistics problem on both mathematics and statistics stackexchange. the answers will most definitely be the same. the religious one is asking for different perspectives on the same thing. the answers will not necessarily be the same.

Comment: @RedRackham - As I said, your question is actually one of the few that *could* be asked on several sites, but it's still regarded as cross posting.

Answer (score 2):

Questions about Christianity and Judaism are more inherently on topic at Islam.SE because the Qur'an (along with other Islamic sources) talks about Christianity and Judaism.  For example:

> And do not argue with the [People of the Scripture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People_of_the_Book) except in a way that is best, except for those who commit injustice among them, and say, "We believe in that which has been revealed to us and revealed to you. And our God and your God is one; and we are Muslims [in submission] to Him."  -- [Qur'an 29:46](https://quran.com/29:46)